# Tomcat 7 hangs on load run. No request received at tomcat

Tags: java, tcp, centos, tomcat7, netstat

There are 3 instance of Tomcat 7. `Load Balancer` redirects request to this 3 server. When load of 500 request per second is given, one of the 3 tomcat gets hangs, no request is received on tomcat. Sometimes even all 3 gets hangs.

`Netstat output` shows following

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60358       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60429       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60165       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60408       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60352       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
tcp     8080      0 10.10.1.97:60518       10.10.1.86:1521        ESTABLISHED
```

When I kill the tomcat process, following is netstat output:

```
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:59990      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:56286      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:56753      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:57180      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:57609      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:62490      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:62274      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:62663      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:62084      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:55357      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.10.1.97:8080        10.10.1.212:61369      TIME_WAIT
```

Tomcat version is

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Server built:   Oct 18 2013 01:07:38
Server number:  7.0.47.0
```

Tomcat port 8080 connector configuration is :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxThreads="500"
           minSpareThreads="75"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

My question is why tomcat hangs and netstat results shows tcp connection in `ESTABLISHED` and not a single request is received when this happens ? What can be configuration changes which can resolve this issue?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Since you have configured the tomcat for 500 threads and your server hangs on 500 to me that means that all the requests are going to one server and you may have a bad configured load-balancer that does not utilize all 3 servers and just uses one of the servers. Check if this is the case

Comment: Load balancer sends request to all three server on round robin  basis.